# Is it possible to install proxy server to DD-WRT?

Tags: proxy, squid, proxy-server

I have DD-WRT x86 version running now on VirtualBox. Is it possible to install **inside** dd-wrt a proxy server (squid if it can run). Is there any documentation available for this tusk?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this post in the DD_WRT forum](http://www.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=80678) this is possible(*)

(*) caveat: although I have run DD-WRT for years I have not installed a proxy on it myself. However the forum says it can be done and several people report having done it successfully.